# how write select query from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a one master table and inserted table. the master table name is `CCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS` and inserted table name is `CUSTCCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS`.
both tables are dependent. Like `CUSTCCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS` is depends on `CCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS`.

for the first time, few fields we have in master table of `CCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS`, and which we have is active `'Y'` those records only I am inserted in an inserted table of `CUSTCCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS` with `ISVISIBLE` `'Y'` or `'N'`.

for the second time in master table few records came so those few records I want to inserted in inserted table so first which records newly came from master table those records I need to show inserted table as `ISVISBLE` `'N'` same time I want show previous which I was inserted in inserted table those all records I need to show and inserted in inserted table.

Please find screen shots

[image: First Time]

[image: Second Time]

So Finally, I want to first showcase table data in both tables whatever missing records as IS visible N and without missing the records as having the isvisible values.

I tried out but we are unable to getting

```html
 SELECT cclf.FIELDNAME AS FIELDNAME,
       CASE ccclf.ISVISIBLE
            WHEN 'Y'  
            THEN 'true' 
            ELSE 'false' 
       END as ISVISIBLE,
FROM CCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS cclf 
LEFT JOIN CUSTCCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS ccclf 
     ON ccclf.ID = cclf.ID AND ccclf.CUSTOMER_ID =2746
ORDER BY clf.ID 
WHERE cclf.ISACTIVE='Y';
```

Comment: what is the expected output from this particular example which you have given?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `verificationTabel`, and you have an extra command after `ISVISIBLE`.

Comment: my expected is I want all data from a master table which is those data have in inserted table I want is visible as 'Y' remaining fields are 'N' and that record finally master data which records we have is active 'Y' those records only I need a select query

Comment: @VKChikkadamalla It would be better that if you can write expected result from your query based on table description in OP.

Comment: @VKChikkadamalla perhaps you are aware that `ccclf.FIELDS_ID = cclf.ID` condition in your query should be `ccclf.ID = cclf.ID`

Comment: In your question, please add one table that contains expected output (columns and data).

Comment: i modified query

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is I am expected output

```html
SELECT cclf.FIELDNAME AS FIELDNAME,
    CASE ccclf.ISVISIBLE WHEN 'Y' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as ISVISIBLE
    FROM appdb.CCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS cclf LEFT JOIN appdb.CUSTCCPCLIENTLOGS_FIELDS ccclf 
    ON ccclf.FIELDS_ID = cclf.ID AND ccclf.CUSTOMER_ID =1984
    WHERE cclf.ISACTIVE='Y' ORDER BY cclf.ID ;
```